# Как средствами C# передать Complex[] с клиента на сервер

Tags: c#, tcp

Отправляю вот так:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Принимаю вот так:

```
    byte[] data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
    while (true)
    {
        // получаем сообщение
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = 0;
        do
        {
            bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
        }
        while (stream.DataAvailable);

        string message = builder.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(message);
        // TODO
   }
```

Такой метод подходит для передачи string или скажем int
А как передать массив и в придачу комплексных чисел Complex[] ??

Comment: Сериализуйте в поток и передавайте его. И читать из потока лучше не через `while (DataAvailable)` — а вдруг сервер будет передавать медленнее, чем клиент читать?

Comment: А как тогда читать?

Comment: Передавайте в начале длину данных, и читайте из потока сначала длину, а потом нужное число байт данных (через `while (totalBytes < neededBytes) totalBytes += await stream.ReadAsync(...);`).

Comment: Проблема в том, что я передаю массивы Complex[] в цикле постоянно. И каждый раз передавать размер каждого нового массива и на серверной стороне считывать?

Comment: И можно пример, хоть простейший?

Comment: Да, каждый раз передавать длину. Это ж всего-навсего 4 байта. // Пример сейчас не напишу, я с телефона. Если никто не напишет до завтрашнего вечера, я вернусь домой и напишу вам пример.

Comment: А я пришел к выводу, что если прочитано 0 байт, то уже все, канал закрыт и можно выходить. Не уверен, что так правильно, но вроде бы работает. Не везде ведь длину шлют. Так то правильно по длине читать, но выходить по DataAvailable нельзя

Comment: Также можно попробовать взять любой из потоковых сериализаторов скормить ему NetworkStream и тогда он возьмет на себя формирование байтового сообщение, которое сам же и сможет прочитать на другой стороне, а не самому мудрить с транспортом.

Comment: Окей, напишу пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должен работать какой-то такой пример:

Отправляющая сторона:

```
async Task SendComplex(Stream s, Complex c)
{
    var reBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(c.Real);
    await s.WriteAsync(reBytes, 0, reBytes.Length);
    var imBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(c.Imaginary);
    await s.WriteAsync(imBytes, 0, imBytes.Length);
}

async Task SendInt32(Stream s, int n)
{
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(n);
    await s.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

async Task SendComplexArray(Stream s, Complex[] array)
{
    await SendInt32(s, array.Length);
    foreach (var c in array)
        await SendComplex(s, c);
}
```

Принимающая сторона:

```
async Task<byte[]> ReceiveBytes(Stream s, int nbytes)
{
    var buf = new byte[nbytes];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nbytes)
        readpos += await s.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
    return buf;
}

Task<int> ReceiveInt32(Stream s)
{
    var bytes = await ReceiveBytes(s, 4);
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
}

Task<Complex> ReceiveComplex(Stream s)
{
    var bytes = await ReceiveBytes(s, 16); // 8 bytes re + 8 bytes im
    var re = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 0);
    var im = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 8);
    return new Complex(re, im);
}

Task<Complex[]> ReceiveComplexArray(Stream s)
{
    var array = new Complex[await ReceiveInt32(s)];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        array[i] = await ReceiveComplex(s);
    return array;
}
```